# Tensor networks and construction of PEPO

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, tensor-network

I have a basic understanding of how to construct the tensors of an MPO (matrix product operator), based on, in part, on [PhysRevA.81.062337](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.81.062337) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1047)), see their equations 5 and 6. **I am looking for a similar formulation for a PEPO (projected entangled-pair operators), the 2-dimensional extension of MPO, given some (simple) Hamiltonian.** The aforementioned paper goes into detail about the authors' optimized construction of a nearest-neighbor interaction Hamiltonian in PEPO formalism, but I can't seem to get it working and would like to try a simpler formulation, even if it is less efficient. All my searching either turns up nothing or the paper I already have, but I feel like there must be other references out there.

Comment: It might help if you clearly state what you are looking for.  Do you want a simple construction for a PEPO for a 2D nearest neighbor Hamiltonian?  For what kind of system?  What do you want to do with it? (Numerics? Analytical modeling? ... )

Comment: @Norbert Schuch, I'd like a general construction mechanism if possible. For example, I can construct an MPO for an arbitrary number of operators so long as the Hamiltonian is a sum of outer products; is there a similar construction mechanism for PEPO, or is the structure strongly dependent on the number of operators? I will eventually be using this for numerical modeling of a 2d or 3d system.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch After doing even more reading, I think I could work from an example of a nearest-neighbor PEPO. The reference "Hand-waving and interpretive dance: An introductory course on tensor networks" has an example of a 1-body field Hamiltonian and a 9-body plaquette, but I don't understand their boundary conditions.

Comment: If you want to use this for simulations, wouldn't it make more sense to first learn about PEPS algorithms and then use the Hamiltonian encoding best suited for the algorithm of choice?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, I'd be happy for you to point me to some references on PEPS algorithms so I can learn more about them. I think the nearest-neighbor Hamiltonian would work best for what I want to simulate.

Comment: Finite? Infinite?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I think finite makes more sense for this system. I am still debating whether or not to use periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: My impression is that infinite tinv. algorithms have been developed much more recently as compared to finite systems.  Also, finite PEPS with PBC will be computationally significantly more costly.